# Извлечение строки из массива JSON как число

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-5.7

В MySQL таблице `mytable` есть колонка `json_col`, в которой данные хранятся в формате JSON следующем виде:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "name":"foo",
            "timestamp":"1612872027"
        },
        {
            "name":"bar",
            "timestamp":"1612872027"
        }
    ]
}
```

я пытаюсь получить все строки, у которых элемент `foo` имеет timestamp больше какой-либо цифры, например нуля:

```
select * from mytable 
  where json_contains(json_extract(json_col, '$.items'), "'foo'", '$[0].name')
  and cast(json_extract(json_col, '$.items[0].timestamp') as bigint) > 0
```

Тут 2 проблемы:

1. `foo` может необязательно быть первым элементом, и непонятно как искать по всем элементам, а не только первому (`$[*]` не работает)
2. Не кастится `timestamp` в `bigint` - как в примере не работает

Версия mysql `5.7.25`

**UPD**

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nyTstzKyvBUzPw1GsWCygD/0

Ожидаю, что первые 2 строки будут выбраны, так как содержат элемент `foo` и у него значение `timestamp` больше 0.
Третья не будет выбрана, потому что у `foo` значение `timestamp` не больше нуля.
Четвертая не будет выбрана, потому что не содержит элемента `foo`.

Comment: Создайте online fiddle (или хотя бы выложите CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO 3-5 записей) и покажите требуемый ответ для таких данных (желательно, чтобы в исходных данных были все варианты значений).

Comment: *непонятно как искать по всем элементам* Вы вообще ничего не ищете - Вы проверяете существование. *Не кастится* А кто UNQUOTE делать будет?

Comment: @Akina Постарался подробно расписать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
WHERE 0 + JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(json_col, REPLACE(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(json_col, 'one', 'foo')), 'name', 'timestamp'))) > 0;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=93bcad77a8394ed493fd0f135fa413e5)

PS. Предполагается, что каждое значение `json_col` содержит только один объект, имеющий компонент `"name": "foo"`. Если их несколько - будет проверен только первый из них.

Comment: Отлично, то, что нужно!